# Use Laravel-filemanager without editor

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, file-manager

I am planning to use the Laravel-filemanager [laravel-filemanager](https://github.com/tsawler/laravel-filemanager) in my project. In the documentation it is described to integrate with the `CKEditor`. But I want to use this file manager separately for a input field.

Comment: So your question is: How can I use this without CKEditor?

Comment: @Dees040, I did not mention CKEditor because i found a fork of the laravel filemanager for TinyMCE. But yes, you are right.

Comment: @nasirkhan Did you find the answer? if you did.. can you share it?

Comment: @FerchoCarcho added the answer of the question, it is https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-filemanager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the library which i was searching for. UniSharp maintain a package **https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-filemanager** which is a fork of [tsawler/laravel-filemanager](https://github.com/tsawler/laravel-filemanager). Do not use the original package developed by tsawler, i does not maintain the package any more and not responsible enough.

Answer (score 0):

It is really easy with Laravel Simple File Manager.

**GitHub:** https://github.com/haruncpi/laravel-simple-filemanager

Example without editor

```
<input id="profile">
<button type="button" onclick="filemanager.selectFile('profile')">Pick</button>
```

You can use it for selecting the batch files/images without using an HTML editor. Read the full documentation of [Laravel Simple Filemanager](https://laravelarticle.com/laravel-simple-filemanager)

Answer (score 0):

Easy

- Code Editor
- File operation(copy,rename,upload,cut,delete,move)
- zip
- unzip
- artisan terminal
- dark/light theme

**GitHub:** https://github.com/srustamov/laravel-file-manager