# Laravel or OctoberCMS Phoca Download Like Kind of Library

Tags: laravel, file, web, directory, octobercms

I need a Laravel or OctoberCMS files and folders view on website front-end. I can use Phoca Download in Joomla to allow users to navigate folders and download files in the folders. Which Laravel or OctoberCMS library I can use to achieve almost similar behavior?

Comment: Here is a really cool plugin that might work

https://octobercms.com/plugin/inetis-downloadmanager

Answer (score 0):

**In case of Laravel:**
First of all Laravel is not a CMS, its actually a framework to develop web applications rapidly. You can get file manager packages for laravel, there are lots of packages/libraries and tools for Laravel but gain you have to manually install and manage those packages in your intended way.

**Laravel File Management - Usefull Links**:
1) [laravel-filemanager](https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-filemanager) 
2) [laravel-elfinder](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-elfinder) 
3) [laravel-medialibrary](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-medialibrary)

**You might like** [Laravel File Manager](https://unisharp.github.io/laravel-filemanager/)

There is huge difference between framework and CMSs. CMS does have easy to install modules/extensions for a particular problem and frameworks too. But most of the time you have to implement best library or package for your framework on your own and use available functionalities on your own.

Laravel has its own native file management system included with Laravel framework:
[Laravel File System](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem)

Random Link: [Use Laravel-filemanager without editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35621440/use-laravel-filemanager-without-editor)

You can develop your own plugins like `Phoca` on Laravel Framework or you can simply utilize one of the available library to update and configure file system as `Phoca`

Answer (score 0):

We have build a Download Manager for October
http://octobercms.com/plugin/inetis-downloadmanager
you will find a demo here : https://demo.inetis.ch/plugins/download-manager
It could fit your needs